Joomla Custom Field Type Plugin No Translateable Label
In my Project I create a Custom Field Type Plugin (my own Customfield Type) - I'm using the new Structure with namespaces but on the "Field Selection" There is no translateable label. Its just the Plugin Name without underscores. See the attached screenshot with language debug enabled and set to CONSTANTS - as you can see the entry for my plugin is not a language constant its hardcoded.
What do I need to change that there is a language constant that can be translated rather than this String?
Sourcecode: https://github.com/marcorensch/NXD_FolderList


If you look at other language constants, you'll see they follow PLG_FIELDS_{ELEMENT}_LABEL pattern. You need to add PLG_FIELDS_NXDFOLDERLIST_LABEL language constant to your language file. Ideally, all language strings in your plugin should be prefixed with PLG_FIELDS_NXDFOLDERLIST_ to prevent conflicts with other extensions and Joomla core strings.

Ok - i don't get it - it makes 0 sense to me but after adding PLG_FIELDS_NXDFOLDERLIST_LABEL to the lang file its displayed as language constant in the selection. Thanks for your help sharky.
